# How to prevent subview go out of superview while rotating and resizing

Tags: ios

I'am going to rotate and resize a view(UIImageView) so that it doesn't go out of supverview.
So I wrote following.

```
    //rotating and resizing process

    //testing subview is in superview
    CGRect rect = subview.bounds;
    CGRect converted_rect = [subview convertRect:rect toView:subview.superview];
    if(!CGRectContainsRect(subview.superview.frame, converted_rect))
    { 
        //restore proccess
    }
```

But my code can't prevent going out of superview area.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard, check the box "clip subviews" in the superview's attribute inspector.  If not, UIView has a property called clipToBounds that you can set to YES.  Both do the same thing, choose whether to use the storyboard or programmatic method based on your project.

Comment: If superview's "clip subviews" attribute is checked, only hide a part of subview that go out superview. can't prevent going out.